# Unable to compile harfbuz_ng library using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, text-rendering

I am developing an application in which i am using [indic-text-renderer](https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/) for devnagri text renderering.As this is NDK library;i am trying to compile it using `ndk-build` command.
But it gives me following error:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'harfbuzz_ng' in /cygdrive/d/Project_WorkSpace/indic-text-renderer//jni/harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by /cygdrive/d/Project_WorkSpace/indic-text-renderer//jni/harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk.
```

My android.mk file is:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE := complex-script-rendering

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/harfbuzz-ng/src

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := complex-script-rendering.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ft2 harfbuzz

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/Android.mk

include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk
```

[image: JNI-hierarchy]

How can i resolve this error?

I am very new to the NDK programming,so pls let me know if this information is not sufficient

**Edit:**

**freetype/Android.mk**

```
ifndef USE_FREETYPE
USE_FREETYPE := 2.4.2
endif

ifeq ($(USE_FREETYPE),2.4.2)
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# compile in ARM mode, since the glyph loader/renderer is a hotspot
# when loading complex pages in the browser
#
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    src/base/ftbbox.c \
    src/base/ftbitmap.c \
    src/base/ftfstype.c \
    src/base/ftglyph.c \
    src/base/ftlcdfil.c \
    src/base/ftstroke.c \
    src/base/fttype1.c \
    src/base/ftxf86.c \
    src/base/ftbase.c \
    src/base/ftsystem.c \
    src/base/ftinit.c \
    src/base/ftgasp.c \
    src/raster/raster.c \
    src/sfnt/sfnt.c \
    src/smooth/smooth.c \
    src/autofit/autofit.c \
    src/truetype/truetype.c \
    src/cff/cff.c \
    src/psnames/psnames.c \
    src/pshinter/pshinter.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/builds \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -W -Wall
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIC -DPIC
LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DDARWIN_NO_CARBON"
LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY"

# the following is for testing only, and should not be used in final builds
# of the product
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += "-DTT_CONFIG_OPTION_BYTECODE_INTERPRETER"

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2

LOCAL_MODULE:= libft2

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endif
```

**harfbuzz-ng/android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES = \
    src/hb-blob.cc \
    src/hb-buffer-serialize.cc \
    src/hb-buffer.cc \
    src/hb-common.cc \
    src/hb-fallback-shape.cc \
    src/hb-face.cc \
    src/hb-font.cc \
    src/hb-ot-tag.cc \
    src/hb-set.cc \
    src/hb-shape.cc \
    src/hb-shape-plan.cc \
    src/hb-shaper.cc \
    src/hb-tt-font.cc \
    src/hb-unicode.cc \
    src/hb-warning.cc \
    src/hb-ot-layout.cc \
    src/hb-ot-map.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-arabic.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-default.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic-table.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-myanmar.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-sea.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-thai.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-normalize.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-fallback.cc

#############################################################
#   build the harfbuzz library
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    $(HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES) \
    src/hb-icu.cc

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        libcutils \
        libicuuc \
        libicui18n \
        libutils

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
        external/icu4c/common

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHB_NO_MT -DHAVE_OT -DHAVE_ICU

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread

LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz_ng

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#############################################################
#   build the harfbuzz static library
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    $(HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES) \
    src/hb-ucdn.cc \
    src/hb-ucdn/ucdn.c

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION     := .cc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := libft2
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
  external/freetype/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHB_NO_MT -DHAVE_OT -DHAVE_UCDN -DHAVE_FREETYPE
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread

LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz_ng

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Can you post contents of `freetype/Android.mk` and `harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk`?

Comment: @ shoe rat:i have put the respective .mk pls have a look

Comment: Why there are two identical `LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz_ng` defined in `harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk`?

Comment: i don't have any idea about it,i have downloaded it.

Comment: That duplicate definition is causing the error in question. Where did you download that .mk file? The link you have provided does not have such content.

Comment: i tried to compile after remmoving `LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz_ng` but no luck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing the entire BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY block and it stopped complaining about re-defining problem,because I wanted to compile harfbuzz-ng just as a static library. You may give it a try.

The last time I got this error,is when I cross compile freetype and use it as a PRE-built static library in my project,I exported the NDK-MODULE-PATH and yet there's a line in my jni/Android.mk written `include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/Android.mk`

So I just comment out this line and everything works fine.

Because when you set NDK-MODULE-PATH , the compiler will look into your PATH directory and search for Android.mk and compile the source with it. please reference [this](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.html),and I hope it will help you .

Answer (score 1):

my jni/Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE := complex-script-rendering

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/include  $(LOCAL_PATH)/harfbuzz-ng/src

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := complex-script-rendering.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libfreetype libharfbuzz

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,freetype)

#include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/Android.mk

include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk
```

and harfbuzz-ng/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES = \
    src/hb-blob.cc \
    src/hb-buffer-serialize.cc \
    src/hb-buffer.cc \
    src/hb-common.cc \
    src/hb-fallback-shape.cc \
    src/hb-face.cc \
    src/hb-font.cc \
    src/hb-ot-tag.cc \
    src/hb-ft.cc \
    src/hb-set.cc \
    src/hb-shape.cc \
    src/hb-shape-plan.cc \
    src/hb-shaper.cc \
    src/hb-tt-font.cc \
    src/hb-unicode.cc \
    src/hb-warning.cc \
    src/hb-ot-layout.cc \
    src/hb-ot-map.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-arabic.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-default.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-indic-table.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-myanmar.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-sea.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-complex-thai.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-normalize.cc \
    src/hb-ot-shape-fallback.cc

#############################################################
#   build the harfbuzz library
#
#
#include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#
#LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
#
#LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
#
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
#   $(HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES) \
#   src/hb-icu.cc
#
#LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc
#
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
#        libcutils \
#        libicuuc \
#        libicui18n \
#        libutils
#
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
#        $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
#        external/icu4c/common
#
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHB_NO_MT -DHAVE_OT -DHAVE_ICU
#
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread
#
#LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz_ng
#
#include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#############################################################
#   build the harfbuzz static library
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    $(HARFBUZZ_SRC_FILES) \
    src/hb-ucdn.cc \
    src/hb-ucdn/ucdn.c

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION     := .cc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := libfreetype
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/hb-ucdn \
  external/freetype/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHB_NO_MT -DHAVE_OT -DHAVE_UCDN -DHAVE_FREETYPE
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread

LOCAL_MODULE:= libharfbuzz

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and I have a build.sh file in my jni directory,which will exort my freetype module,quite simple:

```
export NDK_MODULE_PATH=/home/***/workspace/indic-text-renderer/jni

ndk-build
```

Besides all this, you will have to cross-compile freetype library.

Wish you good luck, it costs me almost a week.